# Run Time Check Failure #2 S C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-value

I'm having trouble on a C++ program. It keeps giving me a Run Time Error # 2 - S. It builds fine though. It builds fine. Main is supposed to call two other functions, one which puts ints into an array, the other which reverses the numbers' positions on the arrays, essentially creating a 'reverse' array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void storeArray(int[], int);
void flipArray(int[], int);

int main()
{
const int arraysize = 10;
int foo[arraysize]; // everyone seems to use foo so I thought I'd try it

storeArray(&foo[arraysize], arraysize);

cout << endl;

flipArray(&foo[arraysize], arraysize);

return 0;
}

void storeArray(int foo[], int arraysize)
{
int counter;
counter = 0;

while (counter < arraysize)
{

    cout << "Enter number " << (counter+1) << " : ";
    cin >> foo[counter];        counter++;

}

return;
 }

void flipArray(int foo[], int arraysize)
{

int counter2;
int counter3;

counter2 = 0;
counter3 = 9;

for (counter2; counter2 <= 9; counter2++)
{

    cout << "Value number " << (counter2 + 1) << " is " << foo[counter3] << endl;

    counter3--;

}

cout << endl;

return;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're passing the address of the end of the array to your functions, use `storeArray(foo, arraysize);` and `flipArray(foo, arraysize);`.

Answer (score 1):

> storeArray(&foo[arraysize], arraysize);

This passes the address *just past* the end of `foo`

Instead use:

```
storeArray(foo, arraysize);
```

And:

```
void storeArray(int* foo, int arraysize)
```

Likewise for:

> flipArray(&foo[arraysize], arraysize);

EDIT: just noticed you're `#include <array>` and using C-style arrays. Not the C++ STL arrays defined in `#include <array>`

Comment: `storeArray` doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: @user657267 yes, but it's not idiomatic so why encourage that?

Comment: It's not idiomatic to hint that the function expects an array?

Comment: @user657267 it's idiomatic to pass a pointer.